# Embedding videos hosted in sharepoint online on external site

Tags: office365, office365api, sharepoint-online, microsoft-graph-api, office365-restapi

I am creating a website for my organization to host our documentation. We have a number of videos that are currently hosted in our Sharepoint Online site that I would like to embed in my new NON-Sharepoint site. Is there a suggested way to perform this action? I looked into using Graph API for this which seems like the correct choice, but I cannot figure out how to translate the https://{company}.sharepoint.com/.../video.mp4 into a url that Graph will understand.

Interestingly, if I am authenticated with Sharepoint and using the chrome browser, I can just throw the https://{company}.sharepoint.com/.../video.mp4 into my html video tags and it works like a charm. This is exactly the behavior I want (it's fine if unauthenticated users cannot play the videos). In IE and Edge however, the videos do not load. Any guidance on this topic would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you mean you want to use the Graph API to embed the video URL to a NON-SharePoint site? Which kind of Graph are you using?

Comment: I have a video on a sharepoint online site, I would like some way to embed that video on a non-sharepoint site. I'm asking if the Graph API is how I would do that or if there is another mechanism I should be using. Thanks!

Comment: If the 'embed' means refer to the video on the SharePoint site, you can use the Office 365 Video REST to get the URL of videos and create the hyperlinks in your site. And the hyperlinks of videos could be played when you login the SharePoint site and have the permission to play it.

Comment: This appears to be exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

To get the embed code for a video that is managed in Office 365 Video.

- Sign into Office 365.
- Select the Office 365 app launcher icon, and then select the Video tile. This takes you to Office 365 Video.
- Navigate to the full playback page for the video managed in the Office 365 Video portal that you want to display on your site.
- On the video page in Office 365 Video, click Embed. A box will appear with the embed code for the video.
- Copy the full embed code. Be sure to include the beginning < and the ending >.
- Once you've copied the full embed code, you can add it to your SharePoint on-premises site or other website.

NOTE: Users must be signed in to Office 365 or SharePoint Online to view a video that is managed in Office 365 Video.

Source: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Embed-a-video-from-Office-365-Video-59e19984-c34e-4be8-889b-f6fa93910581

Comment: (Late comment): Of course, not every O365 customer has Office 365 Video (renamed Microsoft Stream) enabled, and this does not work if we don't have the Video tile.